# MATLAB: Large text file to Matrix conversion

Tags: matlab, matrix, text, transpose

I need to read a text file in MATLAB containing 436 float values in each line (text file size is 25GB, so you can estimate the number of lines) and then convert it to a matrix so that I can take the transpose. How to do it? Won't the format specifier be too long?

Comment: Surely you're not reading 25GB of data simply to take the transpose of it. What are you doing with this matrix? Why do you need to load all of the rows into memory at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the floats in your file are written in a format such that you have `15` digits after the floating point. So we have `17` characters for each float. Then, let's also assume that they are separated by a  character, and that we have a `\n` at the end of each line, so that we will have `436*18=7848` characters in total, which assuming ascii characters will use one byte each. Then, your file uses about `25G` of memory, so you can say that you have `(25*2^30)/7848=3.6041e+06` lines (using 2^30 bytes in a gygabyte, the scale is roughly the same if you prefer the definition as 10^9 bytes)`.

So, a matrix of size `4e6, 436` (I'm assuming a much larger higher bound on your matrix size) will, assuming each float takes `4` bytes, roughly take about `6.48G`. This is nothing crazy, and you can find this amount of contiguous memory to allocate when reading the matrix using the `load` function, given you have a decent amount of RAM on your machine. I have `8G` at the moment, and `rand(4*1e6,436)` allocates the desired amount of memory, although it ends up using the swap space and slowing down. I assume that `load` itself will have some amount of overhead, but if you have `16G` of RAM (which is not crazy nowadays) you can safely go with `load`.

Now if you think that you wont find that much contiguous memory, I suggest that you just separate your file into chunks, like `10` matrices, and load and transpose them separately. How you do that is up to you and depends on the application, and whether there are any sparsity patterns in the data or not. Also, make sure (if you don't need the extra precision) that you are using single float precision.